# How to get the styling of a directive's element in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a directive that uses the dimensions of its element. I've noticed that if the styling is done inline on the element then the related style attributes become available in the link function. However if the styling is done in an external css file (which is what I would like to do) the styling doesn't get applied before compilation. Is there some way around this?

[Plunkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/JeFBbv?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular's jqLite `css` function isn't equivalent to the jQuery implementation. Unfortunately the documentation doesn't emphasize this difference, unlike their emphasis on limitations in other functions. jQuery will do what you're expecting and grab the width whether it's defined in an external stylesheet or in an inline style. Angular's jqLite will only grab it from an inline style. There's an open issue about this: [jqLite .css() retrieves only inline styles](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2866).

Some possible work-arounds:

- Use the `offsetWidth` property instead:

  ```
  elem.prop('offsetWidth')
  ```
- If you decide to include jQuery then it will take precedence and `css` will work as expected